# Combine TinyMCE (jQuery plugin) Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE jQuery plugin.  Currently the only file that's pre-loaded is jquery.tinymce.js.

When my module that uses TinyMCE is loaded, it's initialized with the code below.  When this happens, a slew of TinyMCE files are loaded, which I'm viewing in my Chrome window.  If I click away to another module, then come back, the TinyMCE files are *not* re-loaded, which makes sense; the utility is checking to see what's loaded, and dynamically loading the files it needs.

What I want to do is pre-load all the TinyMCE files I need.  I figured I could just look at the Chrome tab, see the files that are loaded, and have them concatenated into a master TinyMCE file.  I tried to start simple, and concatenate the first file it loads, langs/en.js, right after jquery.tinymce.js.  But that yields a script error of TinyMCE is not defined.  I've messed around considerably and nothing seems to work.

Is there a simple way to do this?  I just want to manually concatenate all the TinyMCE files I need into one master file (well it's not manual, I wrote a simple utility to do it, but that's beside the point).

How can this be done?

Is there some sort of initialize method I can call on the jQuery plugin object to get the process started, *and then* process all of the helper TinyMCE files?

TinyMCE initialization code:

```
data.inputs.itemDescription.tinymce({
    // Location of TinyMCE script
    script_url: '/shared/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

    // General options
    theme: "advanced",
    skin: "custom",
    plugins: "style,layer,table,advhr,advlink,inlinepopups,preview,contextmenu,paste,nonbreaking",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,formatselect,bullist,numlist,link,code,preview",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "tablecontrols,|,hr",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a way to compress tinymce files in the "TinyMCE development package".
It is a simple ant tool, but works as it should.

I strongly advise every tinymce user not to use the jQuery build. It is a source of trouble and the jQuery overhead of object creation makes tinymce slow when it comes to the processing of keyboard input. It is better to use the regular tinymce build and additionally load the regular jQuery lib.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce_compressor) what you're talking about?  It looks like it's building...well, I don't know what it's building.  The different options you can specify produce either jsp, .net, cold fusion etc versions.  I just want a single js file made up of the other files I require.  Is this not possible?

Comment: no, this is not exactly what i was talking about. this is something else. when you download the developement tinymce version there is a build.xml in the first directory which will compress all js-files into one single js file.